# converting TForm win32 app to Win7 gadget (delphi)

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

What is the process of converting win32 application (a small popup window actually) to win7 gadget?
Do I need to convert my exe to activex component, can I still use TForm ?

it would be nice to have support for both Win7 + Vista.

Comment: Are you aware that only Windows 7 supports these gadgets? They are no longer available in Windows 8 and 10. Given, that mainstream support for Windows 7 already ended in 2015 and extended support is going to end on 2020-01-14, do you really want to make the effort?

Comment: Thanks but did you notice I asked this one 10 years ago

Comment: Oops, no, I didn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Windows Vista/7 gadgets are essentially mini-HTML applications. The user interface is composed of pages containing regular HTML, CSS ,images and potentially **ActiveX controls**.

So the only way to use your win32 application into a gadget is convert the application to a Activex Control.

You can read these articles

### Activex

- [Building ActiveX Controls with Delphi](http://pw1.netcom.com/~cherrman/dl030.htm) (This article is old but is still useful)
- [Delphi and Active Forms](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa042099.htm)
- [Converting a standard Delphi Form to an ActiveForm](http://pw1.netcom.com/~cherrman/cvtforms.htm)

### Gadgets

- [Introduction to the Gadget Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370867%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Developing a Gadget for Windows Sidebar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456468%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Bye.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to read German, there is a tutorial at [www.delphipraxis.net](http://www.delphipraxis.net/138229-vista-windows-7-gadgets-mit-delphi.html). Perhaps someone may translate it to English...

Comment: Translated to English via Google: http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.delphipraxis.net/topic162626.html&sl=de&tl=en&history_state0=

Comment: The translation is just rubbish, but I like the "dolphin" ;)

Comment: It says "Seite nicht gefunden"

Comment: @nurettin, seems they moved the forum system during all these years so the post numbers changed. Nevertheless, I fixed the link.

Comment: @UweRaabe danke schön :-)