# Windows 7 sidebar gadgets

Tags: c#, delphi, windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

Do you need to write Windows Sidebar Gadgets in C#, or should I be able to write them in another language, for example Delphi?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the task of your gadget. you could encapsulate logic within a delphi activex and to include in a gadget without problems.

> The Windows Vista/7 gadgets are
>   essentially mini-HTML applications.
>   The user interface is composed of
>   pages containing regular HTML, CSS
>   ,images and potentially ActiveX
>   controls.

Check this link

[converting TForm win32 app to Win7 gadget (delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629401/converting-tform-win32-app-to-win7-gadget-delphi)

Answer (score 8):

Gadgets can be made by JavaScripts.
Check [Developing a Gadget for Windows Sidebar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456468%28VS.85%29.aspx)