# Delphi 5 for Win7 Gadgets?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have a number of complex Delphi5 projects which I am considering upgrading. Could anyone tell me:

1. The earliest version of Delphi I would have to upgrade to in order to develop a `gadget` for Windows7 or can it be done to a good standard with existing ActiveX functionality?
2. In which version of Delphi does it become built for purpose or significantly easier to do for a novice?

Comment: Somehow related is [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1629401/960757) and [`this thread`](http://www.delphipraxis.net/138229-vista-windows-7-gadgets-mit-delphi.html) might help you to start. If all needed for this is available in Delphi 5, I don't know though.

Comment: Which Delphi versions do you have available? Be aware that Emba will only ever sell you the latest.

Comment: I don't think there should be a problem with D5 since you can create ActiveX Forms/Controls with it same as with other Delphi version.

Comment: All Delphi versions can both consume and produce Web services. There's no reason that would force you to upgrade. I don't see what that has to do with Windows 7 gadgets, though. Seems like the first and second paragraphs are non-sequiturs. Please [edit] the question to remove irrelevant information or to clarify how it's relevant.

Comment: Apologies I have edited the question to remove the web service reference. I had read in other threads that it was not worth attempting web service consumption in D5 thus my proposed reason for upgrade.

Comment: Before you spend too much time/money/energy on this, understand that Windows7 gadgets have been pretty much deprecated.  They don't exist in Windows 8, and even Microsoft recommends against their use in Windows 7.  
http://www.zdnet.com/security-flaws-signal-early-death-of-windows-gadgets-7000000724/